# How to make a ProgressBar move in anti Clockwise android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-progressbar

I have a normal progressBar, but I need the progress to move from right to left instead of left to right.
I've tried using

```xml
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
```

and

```xml
android:layoutDirection="ltr"
```

even tried making a custom drawable for it too, made a progress.xml

```xml
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:fromDegrees="-270"
        android:toDegrees="270"
        android:duration = "5000">

    <shape
            android:shape="ring"
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:thicknessRatio="8"
            android:useLevel="false">

        <size
                android:width="20dp"
                android:height="20dp" />

        <gradient
                android:type="sweep"
                android:useLevel="false"
                android:startColor="@color/white"
                android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                android:angle="90"/>

    </shape>

</rotate>
```

still not working

Please I need an idea of how to handle this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try flipping your ProgressBar Simply by setting

```
android:scaleX="-1"
```

Comment: This actually worked for me, thanks @CodeWithVikas

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following flag to your XML, I don't think you need a custom drawable. This should do the trick. What I mean is to add it your ProgressBar XML

```xml
android:rotation="180"
```

```xml
<ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rotation="180"
            />
```

Comment: this will turn the progressBar upside-down. including the text if any.

Comment: @MehranB I did try. It basically did what the OP asked, clockwise to anti-clockwise. I might be wrong.